# how to download file to mobile device from asp site

Tags: asp.net, mobile

im trying to download a file from my asp website onto a mobile device. im currently using this code which works perfectly on desktop devices however does not seem to want to download when accessing the mobile version of the site. Please help

code snippet of desktop and mobile code:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/docx";
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Menu.docx");
        Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/Documents/Menu.docx"));
        Response.End();
```

Comment: It really should't be any different on a mobile device. As a side note, I'd change the content type to be all lower case. It may not matter for all clients, but I'd do it just to be safe. Also, your content type doesn't match your file extension. You have the content type for a PDF document, and the file extension for a Word document. Is the file actually a Word document?

Comment: yes its a word document, please advise me on the correct extension to use

Comment: See [What is a correct mime type for docx, pptx etc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212861)

Comment: changed what needed to be changed however does not download on mobile device still

Comment: Please edit your question to reflect your current code.

Comment: done with edits

Comment: Did you actually look at the link I provided you for the MIME type? It clearly doesn't say to use "application/docx" like you've shown in the updated code.